# Parsing XML file from Internet and Storing in Into SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, xml-parsing

How can I store parsed xml file from internet in SQLite? I want to save a xml file because I want to use the xml to be parse for futher use even without connection.. Does anyone knows how??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: add your code ,what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I've got nothing so far. I'm new in android using database so I don't know much. Can you give some options and how abouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Steps:

1. Make the HTTP call
2. Get the response which would be in XML
3. Parse the XML and insert data into the database.

You could go and search how to implement these steps individually, and if you face any problems, post them.

Comment: the third step is my problem..and my big question is how. sorry,just a beginner..
Is there a way that I can put the whole xml file in sqlite?

Comment: Have problem parsing the XML or inserting into the DB?

Comment: I think its in inserting the xml file in the DB. I got the parsing of the xml but it will be time consuming if I will parse it everytime I will open an activity in my application needing the data in the xml file. Also, my app will be useless without internet connection. I want it working even if there is no connection. Of course the xml file can be updated. Have an idea?? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you have got working? You need to parse the XML, and save the details in your tables. IF there is no internet connection, there is no XML. Simple.

Comment: Yes, but that is what I want. Even without connection, the app should be working with the last data given to it. The last data should be used in the activities without relying on the connection. Can you see what is my problem here?

Comment: Well, when the network is not there, you can fetch the data from the tables, that you have saved before and show it on your activity. You might want to clearly state what your doubts are.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not just sure of what am I doing..I guess I'll try it first. I'll get back to you later. Do you have more knowledge about this stuff,because I want to learn more. I'm just a newbie so there are many stuff I would want to learn. Where can I contact you personally? :)

Answer (score 0):

1.Make HTTP request

2.Make data model

3.Get the reponse and put to model

4.Put model to database

Comment: how will i put the model in the database as a whole?